# Replacement iPhone is missing web history

Tags: iphone, ios, safari, browser-history

I recently replaced my iPhone 6. The phone shows no web history. Can that be restored from original account?

Comment: I've presumed you're using Safari. Please clarify if that is not the case.

Answer (score 1):

Restoring from a backup of your device will restore the browser history.

If you've set up the device as new, you'll need to ensure iCloud was logged in on your old device and Safari turned on, and iCloud logged in to the same account on your new phone and Safari turned on there too.